# Keep getting 403 rateLimitExceeded from Reporting api

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have an application which gets Google Analytics statistics for 28 google users (a.k.a: accounts/logins/emails) from Reporting API.

Every client makes a request to his own ga.data (some metrics for the last 3 days) ones per 10 minutes.

Everything was ok for a long period, but yesterday around 5:00 pm UTC one the GA users started to get 403:rateLimitExceeded error in response.

A cycle of 10 repeating requests gets the same 403 error. In 10 min., the new cycle starts and the result is the same.

All other clients on the same application keep updating well, without getting 403:rateLimit error in return.

I have a "sleep" function for 1 second before making a request. Also I am sending a uniq "quotaUser" in each request. My application makes less than 1 RPS and keeps within 20K requests per day.

As I am aware "403:rateLimitExceeded error" stands for the overall limit of the requests for the whole application per day, however in my case all other clients except this one keep updating properly and the overall daily limit of 50K is not being exceeded.

**UPDATE:**
0:00 UTC this GA user stopped getting "403 error" and now keeps updating well.

Please advise what could be the possible reasons of getting "403:rateLimitExceeded error" for that client and what I can do to avoid getting the same problem again?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was too many failed requests per a little time period, in this case you should wait for quotas reset at midnight